# Does Chrome declarativeNetRequest API support these usecases?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have just read through the specification of the new declarativeNetRequest API of the Chrome webextension API, which replaces the WebRequest API in the future. I tried to figure out, if I will be able to do the same with declarativeNetRequest, what I currently do with WebRequest. Unfortunately, I think there won't be a replacement, but perhaps I'm wrong and someone can correct me. Here are the two usecases:

1. In WebRequest.onBeforeRequest: redirect to the URL of my extension and pass the requested URL as parameter. Filtered are local files with "file://" scheme.
2. In WebRequest.onHeadersReceived: analyze the received headers and redirect depending on header values to the URL of my extension and pass requested URL as parameter. Filtered are <all_urls>.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: 1) [redirect action with regexSubstitution](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeNetRequest#property-RuleAction-type)? 2) Not possible so you can describe your use case on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm 1) does work. I also wonder, how a migration would work. Is there any way to reach out to Google to ask such questions?

Comment: They didn't announce anything new since the initial plans were revealed to the public. You can ask in the [groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions) or on crbug.